# Custom .sty directory with OSX 10.5 and pdfTeXk

Tags: packages, installing, mac, paths

I have a tex project using a custom `.cls` which builds in Windows 7 with TeXlipse + MikTeX.  The `.cls` has a number of CTAN LaTeX contrib package dependencies, which I installed one-by-one with MikTeX (something is wrong with my auto-installer).

This project has the directory structure:

```
src/ <- .tex files here
fig/ <- .pdf figures etc
style/ <- .cls file here
```

This project is checked into a CVS repo and a Mac user needs to be able to checkout and build the latest revision.  This user has: `Mac OSX 10.5.8, pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9`.

What I'd like is to be able to check in these contrib packages into the `style/` directory, and then using some commandline arguments include the `style/` directory in pdfTeXk's search path so it can find the `.sty` files when the user builds `src/document.tex`.

I don't have access to a Mac, but I did try to accomplish the same thing with CentOS 5.6 with no luck.  It seems most `pdflatex` packages (ie `tetex-latex-3.0-33.8.el5_5.6.x86_64.rpm`) expect `.sty` files to be in a strict folder hierarchy.  I tried the `-input-directory` argument and `TEXINPUT` environment variable with no avail.

I'm aware that [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) has a package manager which could download and install the required packages for this user, but I'd like to avoid this for a couple reasons:

1. I'd rather not encourage messing
   with their already-working
   environment with pdfTeXk.
2. My understanding is that TeXShop
   won't auto-install packages during
   the build, which is painful because
   this `.cls` has like 10-20 contrib
   dependencies.

Is there an easy solution here? Perhaps I am just spoiled by the ease of MikTex, but this seems to be a pretty basic functionality.

EDIT: It's worth pointing out that I'm using the commandline on CentOS and I believe the user is doing the same in OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1: Install MacTeX**

If your Mac users install the full [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/) distribution, then the chances of a package being missing are very minimal, assuming you are using packages that are standardly part of MikTeX. TeXLive does require packages to be in a strict hierarchy unless they are located in the same folder as the source document.  There are ways to do what you want, but before exploring them it would be simpler to have the right Mac distribution in place and see if the problem goes away.

**Solution 2: Add an extra `texmf` directory.**

It's not hard to add an extra local `texmf` directory.  See [How to add an extra searchable dir with personal style files to TeXLive, NOT under ~/Library/texmf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5162/2693) (the second part of the answer).

Note that TeXLive is very strict about the structure of the `texmf` directory, so LaTeX packages must be in the `tex/latex` directory.  See [How to have local package overide default package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/how-to-have-local-package-overide-default-package/8359#8359) for details of the structure of the `texmf` directory.

**Solution 3: Make a symbolic link to the extra directory**

There is one other way to implement this. On a Mac, local additions are usually expected to be in `~/Library/texmf`, which should have the directory structure outlined in the linked question above.  Instead of adding an extra local `texmf` directory and giving your `style` directory that structure, you could simply put a symbolic link to your `style` directory in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`.  This way any style/class files will be found as if they were in the right part of the local texmf folder.

Comment: I'll suggest this to the user if I am unable to get it to work with the directory structure I've described and path / commandline flag modifications. As noted in the OP, I'd rather not install additional applications or mess with the current setup if possible.

Comment: @BigChief This shouldn't be anything extra if the user has an up-to-date MacTeX installation.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Is pdfTeXk == MacTeX ? I don't have a Mac and can't find much info on pdfTeXk.

Comment: @BigChief pdfTeXk appears in the console banner when pdftex is run with certain extensions.  In order to find out whether your user has MacTeX, they'd need to do `which pdftex`.  If MacTeX is installed, this should return `/usr/texbin/pdftex`.  If it returns something like `/opt/...` or `/sw/...` then they are using a MacPorts or Fink TeX distribution, which is really not recommended.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Understood. I'll inquire about the path, but I'm probably just going to tell them to install MacTeX.  It seems silly it can't search elsewhere, but that's a moot point.

Comment: @BigChief Both my solution and Herbert's will allow it to search elsewhere, but the elsewhere directory still has to have a minimal directory structure.  But MacTeX really is the way to go with this anyway.

Comment: @BigChief I've added a third solution which won't involve reworking the internal structure of your `/style` directory.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that.  +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine the `$TEXMFHOME` environment variable before running `pdflatex`. Then you can use another directory for class or style files:

```
export TEXMFHOME=style
```

you need only one main tex file in the main directory. For the images you can use the path for `\includegraphics[..]{fig/...}` or alternatively, define

```
\graphicspath={{fig/}}
```

To get all auxiliary files into the source directory run

```
pdflatex --output-director=src/ main.tex
```

the file `main.tex` can use `\include` or `\input` for the other tex files.
The `export TEXMFHOME=...` and the optional argument can be added to the setting of an editor, if you use one.

Comment: @Herbert This will only work for running pdflatex from the command line. If you are working from within an editor such as TeXShop, it won't work without further effort.

Comment: @Herbert Nothing is a big deal if you know how to do it. But your solution won't work using TeXShop, for example, without creating a new Engine file.  You can't simply add shell commands to the pdflatex command as you suggest.  So as a general solution for the average Mac user (who doesn't necessarily use the command line at all) this isn't really one.

Comment: I tried exporting `$TEXMFHOME` to point to the `style/` directory (using the absolute path) as you described, but pdflatex still doesn't find the .sty files in `style/`.  Regarding the graphics, the paths are already set properly.  It may be worth noting that I'm building from inside the src directory (`cd src; pdflatex document.tex`) and figs / cls references are properly relative, but .sty are not because in Windows they've always been on my path.

Comment: @BigChief TeXLive is very strict about the internal structure of the `texmf` directories.  So minimally, style files have to be in `style/tex/latex` in order to be found.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Is pdflatex based on TeXLive ?

Comment: @BigChief pdflatex is an binary that is independent (theoretically) of the distribution.  (I.e. all tex distributions will have a pdflatex binary.)  See the comment to my answer for more details on how to figure out what distribution your Mac user has.

Comment: @BigChief: it depends on the program. `pdflatex` uses the TeX Directory Structure to find files. `xelatex` (`xetex`) instead searches files  recursively. By the way: with `xetex` you can use easily OpenType and true type fonts