# Customizing texdoc - funny search path

Tags: texdoc

I want to ensure that `texdoc cool` opens up `texmf-dist/doc/latex/cool/Content_LaTeX_Package_Demo.pdf` instead of `texmf-dist/doc/latex/cool/cool.pdf`:  My default configuration is this:

```
$ texdoc -l cool
 1 /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cool/cool.pdf
   = Package documentation
 2 /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cool/Content_LaTeX_Package_Demo.pdf
   = EXamples of use
Please enter the number of the file to view, anything else to skip:
```

According to the [`texdoc` manual](http://tug.org/texdoc/doc/texdoc.pdf) this can by done with a local `texdoc/texdoc.cnf` file.  I get that.  But when I checked `texdoc`'s search path I get something funny:

```
$ texdoc -f
texdoc 0.72
Configuration files are:
    absent  /Users/matthew/Dropbox/Library/texmf:~/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-x86_64-darwin.cnf
(*) absent  /Users/matthew/Dropbox/Library/texmf:~/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    absent  /Users/matthew/Dropbox/Library/texmf:~/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-dist.cnf
    absent  /usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/texdoc/texdoc-x86_64-darwin.cnf
    absent  /usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    active  /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
(*) This is the recommended configuration file for your personal preferences.
```

The first three directories look like they have a literal `:~` in them.  If I create config files in `~/Dropbox/Library/texmf/texdoc/` or `~/Library/texmf/texdoc` they are not found.

I think I created this problem when I followed the solution to [How to add an extra searchable dir with personal style files to TeXLive, NOT under ~/Library/texmf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-to-add-an-extra-searchable-dir-with-personal-style-files-to-texlive-not-und) :

```
$ kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME
/Users/matthew/Dropbox/Library/texmf:~/Library/texmf
```

It looks like `texdoc` assumes that `$TEXMFHOME` is a single directory and not a colon-separated list of directories.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Speaking as texdoc's author, I think it is a bug in texdoc. More precisely, it _was_ a bug which should be fixed since version 0.81 (shipped with TeX live 2011).

Comment: On an unrelated note, I think the result  of `texdoc cool` is clearly suboptimal, so the adjustment you wanted to make to your configuration should actually be incorporated in the default configuration file. I'd like to encourage everyone to report such suboptimal (or wrong) results on the texdoc list so that I can fix them. Such user input is very useful for me to keep making texdoc better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mpg: Thanks for letting me know this isn't an issue in the current stable version.

Answer (score 2):

I have three answers.

## Upgrade `texdoc`

Manuel Pégourié-Gonnard ([mpg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1239/mpg)), the maintainer of `texdoc`, says the issue has been fixed since v0.81, which shipped with TeX Live 2011.  I'll verify this when I upgrade my TL.

## Set a KPSE variable

See MPG's comment below.  The KPSE variable `$TEXMFHOME.texdoc` can be used to override `$TEXMFHOME` for `texdoc` purposes only.  I ran

```
$ sudo tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME.texdoc "~/Library/texmf"
```

Now I see:

```
$ texdoc -f
texdoc 0.72
Configuration files are:
    absent  /Users/matthew/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-x86_64-darwin.cnf
(*) active  /Users/matthew/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    absent  /Users/matthew/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc-dist.cnf
    absent  /usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/texdoc/texdoc-x86_64-darwin.cnf
    absent  /usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    active  /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
(*) This is the recommended configuration file for your personal preferences.
```

and if I add to `~/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` the line

```
adjscore(cool) Content_LaTeX_Package_Demo = 10
```

I get:

```
$ texdoc -l cool
 1 /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cool/Content_LaTeX_Package_Demo.pdf
   = EXamples of use
 2 /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cool/cool.pdf
   = Package documentation
```

which is what I want.  Not only that, when I choose Help > Show Help for Package... in TeXShop, it reflects this update.

## Set a environment variable

This was my first answer.  The `texdoc` manual notes that environment variables can be overridden for `texdoc` purposes by suffixing `_texdoc` to them.  So a workaround is to set:

```
$ export TEXMFHOME_texdoc=~/Library/texmf
```

(I'm using the `bash` shell on Mac OSX.)  This has to be put in my `~/.profile` file so it is executed within every shell.

But since I have TeX Live and have already customized it it makes sense to go the TL route rather than environment variables.

Comment: Rather than an environment variable, I suggest you use a KPSE variable, named `TEXMFHOME.texdoc` (same as the envvar but with a dot---actually it's the other way round: the envvar is named after the KPSE var). You can set it either by manually editing a relevant `texmf.cnf` file or by having tlmgr edit on for you, eg `tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME.texdoc "~/texmf"`, exactly in the same way you modified the value of TEXMFHOME in the first place.

Comment: @mpg: That does sound like the "right" way to do it.