# Custom location for style files on OSX

Tags: bibtex, texlive

I'm using TeXLive on Mac OSX 10.9. I created some .sty, .bib, and .bst files that I would like to be accessible to every tex file I compile. The restriction is the location of the files I created is fixed (that is, I am not willing to move them anywhere). I am also not willing to have the path specified in each tex file. These restrictions are because I use the same files across multiple computers and OS's.

Is it possible to tell my TeX distribution where to look for .sty, .bib, and .bst files?

There are many related questions, but most of the answers are "put the files in such-and-such a place", which doesn't work for me. The question [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files]) has lots of information, but only gives solutions satisfying my restrictions for Linux and Windows. I apologize if there's already an answer to my question on this site.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  A comment in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/15925 says correctly that the tree is `~/Library/texmf` on Mac OS

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying it's not possible to have TeX find my files if they are elsewhere?

Comment: I am just trying to say the standard place to put your local files is under `~/Library/texmf`.  Otherwise change the environment variable to point to the directory you wish use, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5162/15925

Comment: Fantastic! I hadn't seen this post, and it answers my question. I'm not sure what the etiquette here is: should I delete my question because it is a duplicate?